# What are the general guidelines for breaking a single kafka cluster into multiple?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Topics in combination with their rich configuration can be used to isolate different workloads within a single kafka cluster. What are some rules of thumb that can be used to determine whether to break a single kafka cluster into multiple?

Multi-data center deployments inherenly call for multiple kafka clusters under many scenarios. What are other common scenarios and considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some scenarios I've encountered where multiple clusters proved useful:

- Teams that need to upgrade Kafka at different rates - some teams are super conservative and basically prefer to not touch Kafka ever. Other teams need to upgrade because they need the new features (Kafka Streams in 0.10.0, time-based indexes in 0.10.1.0) or bug fixes. Aggressive upgraders and conservatives should get separate clusters.
- Some configurations are cluster-wide, and if two use-cases mandate different configurations, you don't have much choice.
- Different performance requirements sometimes mean different hardware, getting Kafka to keep some topics on one set of servers and other topics on another set of servers is a PITA. Different clusters make more sense.
- Similar: some use-cases are experimental and generate unpredictable loads on Kafka, others require very stable and predictable performance. For everyone's sanity, keep them apart.
- Similar: Kafka only has very basic QoS guarantees, so a super active topic (say, clickstream) may cause slow-downs for others (say, payment processing).
- Different SLAs: If a single use-case requires you to jump up in the middle of the night a lot and others don't, perhaps give it its own cluster to reduce rate of jumping.
- Different security requirements: Kafka can selectively secure topics, but I noticed that everyone sleeps better if you put sensitive data on one cluster and in-sensitive data on another. This also relates to performance - SSL encryption takes a huge chunk of CPU, so if you can limit this to one cluster, you may save on hardware/ec2 costs.

Hope this helps :) I'm pretty sure I didn't cover even half of it...